# Database formatting

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone i am looking for a way to get code that i have imputed into the database and maintain the formatting the problem i am having is if i insert code into the database like show below.

```
    <?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'blackwood_services',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'BW Services' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'BW Services' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'rewrite' => false,
      'query_var' => false,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpts', 'revisions') //the editing regions that will support

    )
  );
```

When pulling it back out from the database to view it will view as shown below no spaces just one massive block off text/code no formatting.
i want it to show as formmatted code so i can copy and paste the code.

```
<?php add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' ); function create_post_type() { register_post_type( 'blackwood_services', array( 'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'BW Services' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'BW Services' ) ), 'public' => true, 'show_ui' => true, 'capability_type' => 'post', 'hierarchical' => false, 'rewrite' => false, 'query_var' => false, 'supports' => array( 'title',   'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpts', 'revisions') //the editing regions that will support ) );
```

Comment: what kind of framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you saying, but it sounds like you are storing PHP in a database, which is an interesting idea...

Anyway, you'll want to make sure you escape newlines before storing (i.e. replace them with a \n).

When you render it, stick it in a pre tag to ensure that they show up on a webpage, or use nl2br.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i am try to create a website where i can store snippets off code. i will insert the code into the website it could be any syntax php jquery java etc, but i then want to pull it back out with the same formatt it was inserted but the database seems to strip all white space which is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

before to store you can encode the code snippets using base64_encode. If you retrive data back to user you can decode it by base64_decode.
Arman.